# How to obtain a list of channels from a AVAudioChannelLayout

Tags: ios, swift, macos, avfoundation

An `AVAudioChannelLayout` describes a particular channel layout. The `channelCount` property gives the number of channels. But I found that there is no convenient way to obtain more information about each channel like its name and angular position. Is there a method in `AVFAudio` or some third-party library that I can use to query information about each specific channel?

I found the only way `AVFAudio` gives me anything about each channel is through its layout name. I would get the name like this. It would output something like `"5.1 (C L R Ls Rs LFE)"`

```swift
extension AVAudioChannelLayout {
   func getLayoutName() -> String {
      var cfString: CFString! = nil
      var propertySize: UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout<CFString>.size)
      var rawLayout: AudioChannelLayout = layout.pointee
        
      AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelLayoutName,
                             UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioChannelLayout>.size),
                             &rawLayout, &propertySize, &cfString)
        
      return String(cfString as NSString)
}
```

Then I would parse the string, and lookup each channel name to its property. The problem is that there is no universal specification on what each channel is called at each location. A channel at the same location is called different things under different layouts. And worse, some channels that are called the same thing are in different positions in different layouts. (Source: https://mediaarea.net/AudioChannelLayout)

This string parsing method seems really janky and unreliable. Is there really no better way to do this?

Edit:
I am aware that channel descriptions can exist within a `AVAudioChannelLayout`. But that appears only for the case when `AVFAudio` have no way of reducing it into either the channels bitset, or a tag. I suppose another way of phrasing the question is "how to force `AVFAudio` to always fill in the `mChannelDescriptions` of the `AudioChannelLayout`.

Comment: If your `AVAudioChannelLayout` layout has `mNumberChannelDescriptions` > 0, you can fetch the labels using `kAudioFormatProperty_ChannelName`.

Comment: yes, I am aware of them. But for common formats, like stereo or 5.1, the ```AVAudioChannelLayout``` will choose reduce it into tags, which are cryptic. It is possible to create a large lookup table for these sort of thing, but it's not the solution I am looking for.